# Change jQuery icon color to white instead of gray

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use jQuery icons in my asp.net mvc project. Usually I use gray icons but now I would like a white icon for my blue button (see below).

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
$(".editUser").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-pencil"} });
$(".deleteUser").button({ icons: { primary: "ui-icon-trash"} });
```

**How can I change the icon color to white?**

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can play around with the sprite used on that icon set:

[White Icon Set (ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png)](http://strd6.com/stuff/jqui/theme/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png)

Store that sprite somewhere, then reference it in a style sheet you can apply to the blue buttons:

```
.ui-icon-white {
  background-image: url("images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png");
}
```

Then when you want a white icon set, apply that style:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-white ui-icon-pencil"></span>
```

Comment: Update: The above link for the white icon set is dead. Here is another link: http://strd6.com/stuff/jqui/theme/images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png

Answer (score 0):

Use [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/) to change font color easily:

```
$(".editUser").button({
  html: '<span class="fa fa-check"></span> Yes',
  "class": 'bg-success text-white p-2 border-0',
  icons: { primary: "ui-icon-pencil" }
});
```

Comment: Yes Font Awesome is a great product, thanks for sharing.