# How to get the coloured JQuery icons instead of black

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery theme "mint-choc" in my page.  All the icons inside the widgets show up as green. I can do the following to add icons to my own DOM objects:

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span>
```

While the icons do show up just fine, they are black--not the same colour as the theme I'm using. Is there another class I'm supposed to add in order to change the colours to the same ones that my theme is using?

Comment: Just a site note - if you would use a icon font like http://icomoon.io/ you could change the icon color with the `color` css property.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028633/having-a-jquery-icon-showed-in-white-and-not-gray

Comment: @ftom2: I've tried the solution on the page you mentioned, but it didn't work. I even tried downloading the image and saving it to my images directory but to no avail.

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle :)

Comment: I'd recommend you to use icon fonts. Here's the free collection(Just like Google WebFonts): http://weloveiconfonts.com/

Comment: @SonuJoshi - OP is using jquery UI which comes with default icons, and it is easier to use them instead of integrating your own.

Comment: JQuery UI icon are an image right positioned using CSS. You can't change color without creating a new icons image using the theme maker. Instead, I highly recommend the excellent Font Awesome. It working as real font, so you can change icons color using CSS syntax color : http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default icon set for `ui-icon` is:

```
.ui-icon,.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
```

This image is the set of black icons.

For green you want to add this class

```
.ui-state-default .ui-icon {
   background-image: url(images/ui-icons_9bcc60_256x240.png);
}
```

There are six different colors for the icons.  Look at the css file starting at line 929 to see all of them.

If you inspect the theme page you can see that each icon is set up like this:

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" title=".ui-icon-carat-1-e">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-e"></span>
</li>
```

Changing the `ui-state-default` to any of the following to change the font color.

- ui-widget-content
- ui-widget-header
- ui-state-focus
- ui-state-active
- ui-state-highlight
- ui-state-error